# Using buildTree to generate array of all possible branches

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I'm using a buildTree function found on here to get all children of a parent, but I'm struggling to adapt the code to generate all possible branches down through the tree.

**Sample data:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [parent_id] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [parent_id] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [parent_id] => 7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [parent_id] => 7
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [parent_id] => 17
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21
            [parent_id] => 17
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [parent_id] => 17
        )
)
```

**buildTree:**

```
function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
    $branch = array();
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
                if ($children) {
                    $element['children'] = $children;
                }
                $branch[] = $element;
            }
        }
        return $branch;
    }
}
```

**What I'm trying to output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            6, 7, 17, 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            6, 7, 17, 21
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            6, 7, 17, 22
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            6, 7, 18
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            6, 8
        )
)
```

I've tried using a foreach loop instead of `if($children)` to generate the next key in the resulting array and to merge in the existing data from higher up the tree, but with no success.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your buildTree function there are couple of errors. First of all you cannot check for nonexisting keys in array such as "parent" (there is "parent_id").

Please check if this is what you're looking for:

```
<?php

$input =
[
  [
    "id" => 7,
    "parent_id" => 6
  ],
  [
    "id" => 8,
    "parent_id" => 6
  ],
  [
    "id" => 17,
    "parent_id" => 7
  ],
  [
    "id" => 18,
    "parent_id" => 7
  ],
  [
    "id" => 20,
    "parent_id" => 17
  ],
  [
    "id" => 21,
    "parent_id" => 17
  ],
  [
    "id" => 22,
    "parent_id" => 17
  ]
];

function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0)
{
    $branch = array();
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
            if (!empty($children)) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}

print_r(buildTree($input, 7));
```

Comment: Thanks Karol. "parent" was a typo, corrected now. My buildTree works great at generating a nested array, but I need to adapt it to generate arrays of each possible route down through the tree.